# How to ingnore specific parent class and count rest

Tags: jquery, html

I have situations like count some `li` that is not under multiple classes.

```
<div class="col_one_half">
<ul>
  <li class="individual_short_code_li"></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="col_one_fourth">
<ul>
  <li class="individual_short_code_li"></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="col_one_third">
<ul>
  <li class="individual_short_code_li"></li>
</ul>
</div>

<ul>
  <li class="individual_short_code_li"></li>
</ul>
```

In this HTML section , I have to count the `individual_short_code_li` class that is not under `.col_one_half .col_one_third .col_one_fourth .col_two_third .col_three_fourth` classes.

I tried this with `not()` selector. but not working correctly.

```
jQuery('.individual_short_code_li' ).not('.col_one_half, .col_one_third, .col_one_fourth, .col_two_third, .col_three_fourth').length;
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M7NPP/)

Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
$("div.item-page > *").not('.col_one_half, .col_one_third, .col_one_fourth, .col_two_third, .col_three_fourth').find('.individual_short_code_li').length;
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DDxQ7/)**

Comment: I don't have div for last one then How to get it ?

Comment: what is the parent dom of above DOM. can you share it??

Comment: all this area comes under ".account_section" class,the issue is when run the code its getting or counting all the "individual_short_code_li"

Comment: Yes, It almost did, but count should be 33 but its 32

Comment: can you see here in console which one are we missing http://jsfiddle.net/DDxQ7/1/

Comment: Sorry its my mistake while creating fiddle I missed one li its works fine Great thank you..